# Is it worth it to have separate namespaces for interfaces and implementations?

Tags: c++, c++11

Is it worth it to have separate namespaces for interfaces and implementations?

Stroustrup's advice in his C++ book (fourth edition) is that we should use separate namespaces
for interfaces and implementations. Can the more experienced folks say something
on this one? I mean it sounds nice, but is it really practical, does it make sense in
real world projects?

Comment: If it didn't make sense he wouldn't have mentioned it.

Comment: I'm interested in the answer too. Didn't read this one. Which book are you mentioning by the way?

Comment: @dan sure I trust him too :), but I wanted to hear more about the reason behind it, and experiences from real world projects.

Comment: @DavidKernin I modified my post, it is the fourth edition of C++.

Comment: I have it but still haven't read it, thanks! I'll await for an answer from someone who knows more :)

Comment: Do you mean "The c++ programming language, 4th edition for C++11?

Comment: @RobertJacobs Is there some other C++ book fourth edition by Stroustrup?! :)

Comment: I just thought you should put the entire title somewhere in the question.

Comment: *"does it make sense in real world projects?"* Yes, for example in `boost` it's widely used. Take [`boost::shared_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp) for example. As soon as I see `namespace detail` I immediately know that I don't have too look into that code segment, unless there's an error message telling me to do so.

Comment: if I may, this is a great question and I'd recommend OP to keep this open for a day or so in order to gain all possible answers and really pick the best one up. I hope you're not in a hurry :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A namespace tells you something about who the definition belongs to. Of course it makes sense for the interface to belong to a different group than the implementation; that's the whole point of interfaces, separation of concerns.

Comment: Basically, we can think of a namespace as a class. Sometimes we want to make certain parts private(for the implementer) and others public (for the user). Since we can't do that with namespaces, we can only create separate namespaces then. So that is the whole point of this advice I guess.

Comment: @user3111311 Thinking of namespaces in terms of classes only confuses the issue.

Answer (score 2):

In code that is heavy on implementation (say, some meta-programming monstrosity inside Boost), it can be useful to spot at a glance which code you are expected to be able to use directly, and which code you can safely ignore. Code in a library's `detail` namespace is deemed to be "internal" code, so you don't need to spend time hunting through documentation when you see a `detail` symbol in a stack trace.

I wouldn't say there's a *huge* benefit to it and certainly not so in the general case, but since it doesn't do any harm you might as well keep things tidy and segregated.

Answer (score 0):

> does it make sense in real world projects?

Yes, for example in boost it's widely used. Take [`boost::shared_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp) for example. As soon as I see `namespace detail` I immediately know that I don't have too look into that code segment, unless there's an error message telling me to do so (and even then, it's most likely my fault).

### Obligatory contrived real-world inspired example

I guess you know how to steer a car. There are many interfaces: the steering wheel, the gas/break/clutch pedals, the displays and so on. You're interested in using those interfaces, after all, this is how you use your car:

```
namespace the_company{
  struct wheel{
    void turnLeft(deg);
    void turnRight(deg) { turnLeft(-deg); }
  };
  struct pedal{
    void tap();  
    void press_completely_till_something_happens(); 
      //!< might deadlock if using break and car isn't moving
  };
  struct display{
    so_many_colors lookat();
  };
}
```

For the sake of this example we're going to group them together as a car, but splitting things into different namespaces isn't only practical for OOP.

```
namespace the_company{    
  struct car{
    public:
      wheel & getWheel();
      pedal & getBreakPedal();
      ...
  };
}
```

What can we expect of `car`? We can expect that we can use the car's wheel or pedal and it will work:

```
car myCar;
myCar.getGasPedal().press_completely_till_something_happens();

// OH GOD; WHAT HAVE I DONE!?

myCar.getWheel().turnLeft(360);

myCar.getBreakPedal().press_completely_till_something_happens();
// Shew. That was close.
```

And we're completely fine using that `car`. By the way, we didn't put `wheel` into `car` since our company might produce other things that use a wheel, such as boats, trucks, contrived planes, valves and other non-vehicle things, and a `display` might get used by even more different things (phones, monitors, TVs, you name it).

However, in order to actually run the car, it must have an engine. Since engines are some rather complicated machinery, we hide them under the `hood`:

```
namespace the_company{
  namespace hood{
    struct engine{
      // heavily optimized code
      // not so nice interface anymore
      // maybe not even documentated
      ...
    };
  }
}
```

That `engine` is a beast, it's scalable and can work for any vehicle or heavy machinery, and your company put much effort into optimization. Now whenever a car owner has a problem with his engine, he can simply look into `hood` and check what's wrong.

But the fact that it's hidden behind something already tells the user from the beginning that he should know what he's about to do. And if he doesn't understand the metal/code, he should ask his service maintenance/support for help.

Furthermore, the `engine` might change or even get completely removed, because our company invented the `fusion_engine`, which gives better profit.

And that's what `namespace detail` is to me: intricate details, that might change and even might only make sense to the original maintainers. But that's fine. It's not part of the interface.

Comment: While this was very inventive, it was such a poor example of OO and even of namespace use that I don't think it really helped :P

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I hardly remember writing this _thing_ at all. Must have happened between waking up and the first sip of coffee.

Comment: Haha. Still, worth keeping :)